# google admob Ad serving is limited .. More than 4 month

Tags: admob

it has been more than 4 months with this ad serving limit
what should I do?
I did search for the support email but they only give me a link to the forum, I did post a question there but without any response.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Nop, not really.. now I'm using Facebook ads instead

Comment: @Akhele Does Facebook ads require mediation to work. Or it work without ad mediation as well...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support questions are off-topic

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I searched on internet and on YouTube found that you have to remove your ad unit( delete your ad unit) so that your traffic is limited and use frequency capping in ad settings.
Using frequency capping you can limit your number of interstitial ads per user per day.
I suggest it to 10 ad per user per day.
And now wait for 3-4 days so that policy violation is removed.  Abd then create new ad units with frequency capping .

Comment: does your method work ? I mean using frequency capping with **10 ads per 1 day**

Comment: No not really after one day of publishing my i got again admob serving limited. And this time it can't detect ad.txt file in my app website. I think i have to wait more. Policy is dated with old date  means it is just disappeared and now it is here.

Answer (score 0):

It's time to move on with other monetization networks.
I also faced same incident with admob now I'm using Facebook audience network which is giving me fair earning.
For reference you can watch this video.
https://youtu.be/Dj-f_ozSepE

Comment: I guess I'll do the same, but I will need to update all the apps 

Comment: I also received a violation from fb audience network 
Even after removing ads, it still refuses to delete violations
...admob seems merciful compared to audience network dealing

Comment: @prathmesh, Does Facebook ad work only with mediation. My app with Facebook ad is showing on test ads no real ads inspite of it being on the Play store.

Comment: Facebook ads work standalone it is not mandatory to have mediation. Most of the time facebook shows their own ads. If your app is Live on store it is showing real ads. but your users should have facebook app installed on there phone then only it works. This is the reason you may see huge difference in revenue of admob & Facebook audience network.